# Adding UILabel for In App Purchase Product Price

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have in app purchases set up in my app which work fine, however I want to call the 'Product Price' with local currency onto a viewController.

I have 2 files set up with the InAppPurchase code in there which look like this:

**InAppPurchaseSS.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import  "StoreKit/StoreKit.h"

#define kProductPurchasedNotification       @"ProductPurchased"
#define kProductPurchaseFailedNotification  @"ProductPurchaseFailed"
#define kProductPurchaseCancelledNotification  @"ProductPurchaseCancelled"

@interface InAppPurchaseSS : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver,UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    SKProductsRequest*   productsRequest;
    SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
    UIAlertView* waitingAlert;
    BOOL isTransactionOngoing;
    IBOutlet UILabel *productPriceLabel;
}

@property (retain) SKProductsRequest*   productsRequest;
@property (retain) NSArray * products;
@property (retain) SKProductsRequest *request;
@property (assign) BOOL isTransactionOngoing;

+ (InAppPurchaseSS *) sharedHelper;

-(id)init;
- (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases;
-(void)restoreInAppPurchase;

@end
```

**InAppPurchaseSS.m**

```
//
//  InAppPurchaseSS.m
//  Pharaonia
//
//  Created by iMac on 4/16/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Apple. All rights reserved.
//

#import "InAppPurchaseSS.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation InAppPurchaseSS

@synthesize products;
@synthesize request;
@synthesize productsRequest;
@synthesize isTransactionOngoing;

static InAppPurchaseSS * _sharedHelper;

+ (InAppPurchaseSS *) sharedHelper {

    if (_sharedHelper != nil) {
        return _sharedHelper;
    }
    _sharedHelper = [[InAppPurchaseSS alloc] init];
    return _sharedHelper;

}

-(id)init {

    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        isTransactionOngoing=NO;
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    }

    return self;

}


- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Received products results...");
    self.products = response.products;
    self.request = nil;    
    NSLog(@"Number of product:%i : %@",[response.products count],response.products);
    NSArray *product = response.products;
    proUpgradeProduct = [product count] == 1 ? [[product firstObject] retain] : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    [productPriceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"Product Price: %@",proUpgradeProduct.price]];




}



-(void)restoreInAppPurchase
{
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {        
        NSLog(@"No internet connection!");   
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet"  message:@"Sorry, no internet connection found"   delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        return;
    }
    waitingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restoring..."  message:@"Please Wait...\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [waitingAlert show];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}




- (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

    if ([productIdentifier isEqual: @""]) {
        NSLog(@"No IAP Product ID specified");
        return;
    }

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; 
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {        
        NSLog(@"No internet connection!");   

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet" message:@"Sorry, no internet connection found"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        return;
    } 
     isTransactionOngoing=YES;

    waitingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchasing..." message:@"Please Wait...\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [waitingAlert show];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0) {
        SKMutablePayment *payment = [[SKMutablePayment alloc] init];
        payment.productIdentifier = productIdentifier;
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
}



-(void)enableFeature
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"PurchaseSuccess"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [waitingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Restore completed transaction failed");

}

- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

//
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful
{
    isTransactionOngoing=NO;
    [waitingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    if (wasSuccessful)
    {
        [self enableFeature];

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!!" message:@"You have succesfully Purchases." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"successbuy" object:self];
    }
    else
    {
      [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:transaction.error.localizedDescription  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TransCancel" object: self];
    }
}


- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"succesfull transaction");
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"transaction is restored");
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}


// called when a transaction has failed
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    isTransactionOngoing=NO;

    NSLog(@"failed transaction called");

    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction failed called");
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);

        [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [waitingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"user cancel transaction");
        // this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TransCancel" object: self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver methods

// called when the transaction status is updated
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"transaction status updated");
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
} 

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

I have another viewController set up where I want to call the Local Product Price with UILabel. Let's assume this is called SecondViewController. I know that in InAppPurchaseSS.m I have a field for **proUpgradeProduct.price** but I need to call this as a UI label with the local currency

It may be something obvious Im overlooking but I'd appreciate some help with this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[SKProduct](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKProduct/priceLocale) has a `priceLocale` attribute and `price` attribute you can use to create the text for your label.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

Comment: Thanks I have already seen this online but it doesnt solve my question. I don't know how to add that code into a new viewcontroller without getting errors

Comment: To get your products from your other controller, call [[InAppPurchaseSS sharedHelper] products]. Then you can use the product here, and the code above to get the formatted string for your label.

Comment: [[InAppPurchaseSS sharedHelper] proUpgradeProduct]; I tried this but it tells me there's no visible interface. Do I have to do something elsE?

Comment: Your proUpgradeProduct is a private variable. Make it public by adding is as a method, or a property/sythesize pair. Your problems are not related to in-app purchasing, but rather a lack of basic objective-c knowledge. I would suggest reading up on a few basic obj-c / ios tutorials.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code for this? I am a newbie and still finding it very difficult. I'd sincerely appreciate your help

Comment: Start by reading the Apple developer docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html